# Finding out bus stops on a set path/polyline

Tags: google-maps

My app now finds the route between 2 locations (transit locations). In the bus/train polyline I wanted to find what are all the bus stops available, since google maps directions api doesn't provide any results of intermediate stops.

How does one know what are the bus stops in the route?

Is the only way to obtain that is to decode the polyline and get all latlng objects and then find them from places api? - This would ping the google places api n times as many latlng objects are found, so if there is anyone who has done this before, please share your thoughts.